# permanently uninstall Realtek and Nvidia drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, group-policy, device-manager

Because of some performance issues on my Dell XPS 15 which i'm not going to address in detail, i want to uninstall the drivers for its Realtek soundcard and for its Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 video card.

Unfortunately, everytime i uninstall the devices via Windows 10 Home `device manager` or via Windows Apps, the devices will be reinstalled after restarting the computer.
I've changed the restriction settings for device installation via `gpedit.msc`, which i first had to install with a Batch Script that i found on some site, since Win 10 Home isn't delivered with `Group Policy Editor`. I activated the restrictions for device installation and added the `Class GUID` of each device to a list in the settings. I even checked the box *"including already installed devices"*. I then did the same thing with `Hardware-ID` of each device.

Besides that, i deactivated automatic driver installation for new hardware components (which should be an unnecessary step).

Actually, the Realtek soundcard stay uninstalled after rebooting, now, which is a surprise to me, because i tried the aforementioned steps multiple times, without success for **both** devices.
At this point, i really don't have high hopes that it will stay this way.

The Nvidia-Apps are still uninstalled but the `device manager` still recognices it. There is also an annoying pop-up that says *"NVIDIA-Systemsteuerung nicht gefunden" (Nvidia system control not found)*.

Any ideas on how to uninstall the Nvida video card for good?

Comment: When uninstalling via Device Manager, to permanently remove the driver you must tick the box to remove installation files, else Windows will re-install upon a reboot. Generally speaking, you should first try uninstalling from `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features`. Just an FYI, for drivers other than Chipet and GPU, it's best to use the component's OEM's site for drivers _(PC OEMs normally customize the generic GPU drivers and generally stop providing driver updates on their site after 1 - 2yrs, once the consider the model EoL [End of Life])_.

Comment: You haven’t been required to use OEM drivers for  Nvidia hardware in over a decade.  However, you won’t be able to have Nvidia hardware, and not have the display driver installed.  I assume you have uninstalled the GeForce Experience software?

Comment: Usually, you want to uninstall the drivers completely to replace them, and yes, upon a reboot windows will install them again. I found it best to first uninstall them in device manager, then when windows says: please reboot, I just ignore it. I then install the drivers outside of device manager and if the hardware was not found by then, scan for hardware changes to get it installed properly, optionally referring to the new drivers. After that, I do reboot. This is usually how I get the hardware with different drivers. Really don't need the hardware, disable it.

Comment: Thanks to all commenters!
I did check the boxes upon uninstalling the devices in `device manager`, everytime.
What i ended up doing is disable the video card. There is still one backgound process running called "Nvidia container", but other than that nothing from my video card. I hope that solves my problem. Time will tell